# multiple values for One Key values dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an Address object in this object I have address lines. My problem is that I want to add different values for same keys. This object can have multiple addresses so I need to add property of address as key and value as value in a dictionary.

suppose object of address one have...

```
City : Kanpur 
State:UP
```

and in second object of address have

```
City : Rajsthan 
State:MP
```

now how can I add it in a generic collections.
I have tried below code. but not getting what is right approach.

```
foreach (var objAddress in entity.Addresses)
{                  
     ds = new Dictionary<string, string>();                           
     ds.Add("City", (objAddress.City == null) ? "" : objAddress.City);
     ds.Add("State", (objAddress.State == null) ? "" : objAddress.State.ToString());
     lsb.Add(ds.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `Dictionary<string, List<Address>>`.

When adding to that Dictionary, if a given key doesn't yet contain a value, add a new `List<Address>` that contains that address.

If the given key does contain a value, simply `Add` the new `Address` to that `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Lookup class. Do:

```
var cityLookup = entity.Addresses.ToLookup(i => i.City);
```

Then you can return the data, grouped by City.

You can create similar lookups for the other properties you're interested in.

When you use a Lookup, it returns a collection of all the matching address.

To look up and work with all the addresses in city "Kanpur", you can do the following:

```
foreach (var address in cityLookup["Kanpur"])
{
    // your code here 
}
```

Comment: but how can i judge that which values is for which address: Suppose given address is for corresponsence address1 City : Kanpur
State:UP
and this address is correspondence address2

City : Rajsthan
State:MP

Comment: The example above gives you an object, where you can look up a city, and return all the addresses with that city. You can make similar lookups for other properties, such as state. Then, depending on what you're searching for, you can choose your lookup accordingly.

Comment: if in the lookup object i am just adding two cities 1.Kanpur that is belong to correspondence address1 and 2.Rajesthan which belongs to correspondence address2. now form the lookup object how can i guess. can you provide some code or demo values

Comment: See updated answer, which includes sample code for using the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a class which holds the complete address and the value of the dictionary can be a collection..

```
Class Address
{
   public string City { get;set; }

   public string State{ get;set; }

   public string Country{ get;set; }
}

var ds = new Dictionary<string,List<Address>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Got the answer....
I am just creating a list of dictionary type and adding multiple values in it.

 Dictionary<string, string> ds = null; 
 List<Dictionary<string, string>> lsb = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
 foreach (var entity in abc.Object)
                            {
                                foreach (var objAddress in entity.Addresses)
                                {
                                     ds.Add("City", (objAddress.City == null) ? "" : objAddress.City);
                                    ds.Add("State", (objAddress.State == null) ? "" : objAddress.State.ToString());
                                    lsb.Add(ds);
                                }
```